# Breadth First Search vs. Best First Search

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, branch-and-bound

What is the main difference between Breadth First Search and Best First Search? What is meant by saying Breadth First Search requires previous knowledge?

Comment: Where have you seen that "Breadth First Search requires previous knowledge"?

Answer (score 3):

In Breadth First Search, nodes are processed by non-decreasing value of their depth, i.e. the next node processed in the unprocessed node with the smallest depth.

In Best First Search, a value is assigned to each unprocessed node. The next node processed is the unprocessed node with the smallest value.
Therefore, Breadth First Search is equivalent to a Best First Search where the value assigned to each node is its depth.

From an implementation point of view, Breadth First Search can be implemented with a simple queue while Best First Search will generally require a priority queue.